# SQLite database with installed program - Permissions

Tags: .net, sqlite, permissions

I'm not sure how to properly handle following scenario:

1. My program installs with installer
2. I create SQLite database in application folder (when program starts)

In some configurations I get "Attemt to write to read-only database" error. This is permissions issue and right now I'm solving it by marking main EXE as "Run as Administrator"

Seems like this is folder permission under "Program Files"

Question is: Should I create database in different location? Or somehow add "Run as administrator" attribute to my EXE automatically(which I don't think possible). My application runs as a service as well so having one central place for database is what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to create database in application folder, this path works without permission issues:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\MyCompany"
```